# Encrypting and decrypting messages with Spring Kafka

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using Spring Kafka and one of the topics contains messages with personal data. Is there any way I can configure Spring Kafka to automatically encrypt messages in a Producer/decrypt messages in a consumer or would I have to do it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built into Spring or Kafka (although you can use SSL on the wire to prevent snooping.

For application-level encryption/decryption, you would need to implement it.

You can separate the concern from your business logic by using a `ProducerInterceptor` and `ConsumerInterceptor` (Kafka) or `RecordInterceptor` (Spring).

Comment: Cheers Gary, we need application level encryption as we are planning to use Amazon MSK. I'll look into the interceptors, does spring have an equivalent producer interceptor?

Comment: No; it's not really needed - the reason we added the `RecordInterceptor` is so you can intercept records one-at-a-time; the `ConsumerInterceptor` gives you the complete set of records returned by the `poll()`. We have users that prefer the one-at-a-time approach. On the producer side, there is always just one record to intercept.

Comment: Ok understood, I’ll implement. Thanks for the support.