# Is there a way to encrypt data before writing to a Kafka topic using JDBC Connector?

Tags: encryption, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We are new to using Kafka (Confluent platform) and have a project using the JDBC source connector. With this approach, is it possible to also encrypt the data to hide personal information, etc. when that data is stored on the topic? Or will we need to take a different approach?

I understand if we were using producer API we would do the encryption prior to writing to the topic - such as is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58717351/encrypting-and-decrypting-messages-with-spring-kafka). I have also found a [KIP](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-317%3A+Add+end-to-end+data+encryption+functionality+to+Apache+Kafka) that discusses the *desire* for end-to-end encryption but it seems that it has not been implemented.

We will be using TLS to protect the data on the wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka Connect comes with an anonymization transformation to hide personal information, however, not an encryption. For the anonymization you can make use of the built-in single message transformation (SMT) called "MaskField" (see below). Encryption is not yet available but you are always free to add your [custom SMT](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/custom.html#custom-transformations) with an encryption of your choice.

According to the documentation on [MaskField](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/maskfield.html#maskfield) you can use it to

- Mask specified fields with a valid null value for the field type (i.e. 0, false, empty string, and so on), or
- Replace any string or numeric field using the replacement property.

An example for both usages of the configuration is also provided in the mentioned link:

```
# Mask Value
"transforms": "MaskField",
"transforms.MaskField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.MaskField$Value",
"transforms.MaskField.fields": "string_field"

# Replcae Value
"transforms": "SSNMask,IPMask,PhoneMask"

"transforms.SSNMask.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.MaskField$Value"
"transforms.SSNMask.fields": "SSN"
"transforms.SSNMask.replacement": "***-***-****"

"transforms.IPMask.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.MaskField$Value"
"transforms.IPMask.fields": "IPAddress"
"transforms.IPMask.replacement": "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

"transforms.PhoneMask.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.MaskField$Value"
"transforms.PhoneMask.fields": "office,mobile"
"transforms.PhoneMask.replacement": "+0-000-000-0000"
```